# Error in twisted matrix: The usePTY parameter is not supported on Windows

Tags: python, twisted, simulation, telnet, pty

I am trying to run the sample code example from the twisted documentation for a PTY server that spawns a shell on connection.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class FakeTelnet(protocol.Protocol):
    commandToRun = ['/bin/sh'] # could have args too
    dirToRunIn = '/tmp'
    def connectionMade(self):
        print 'connection made'
        self.propro = ProcessProtocol(self)
        reactor.spawnProcess(self.propro, self.commandToRun[0], self.commandToRun, {},
                             self.dirToRunIn, usePTY=1)
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.propro.transport.write(data)
    def conectionLost(self, reason):
        print 'connection lost'
        self.propro.tranport.loseConnection()

class ProcessProtocol(protocol.ProcessProtocol):

    def __init__(self, pr):
        self.pr = pr

    def outReceived(self, data):
        self.pr.transport.write(data)

    def processEnded(self, reason):
        print 'protocol conection lost'
        self.pr.transport.loseConnection()

f = protocol.Factory()
f.protocol = FakeTelnet
reactor.listenTCP(5823, f)
reactor.run()
```

This code gives an error "The usePTY parameter is not supported on Windows". I was hoping for a workaround or anything that might help running it on windows.

Comment: The example itself is intended to show something that can be done with Twisted.  As you can see, you can't do what this example wants to do on Windows.  However, whatever you're actually interested in doing may still be possible.  For your next question, I suggest asking about your actual interest, rather than the limitations of a particular example. :)

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Thanks, I basically want to create a shell through this which I can telnet to. This shell can then serve as a personal cli which can then be used to do other stuff

Comment: @Strommer If you want to replicate the Windows command-line, you're mostly out of luck.  Windows makes it very hard to faithfully relay the output of terminal programs to the web.  If you want to write your *own* command line, implementing all of your own commands, there are some other things you can do... but you'll need to open a new question, and explain what sort of commands you expect to be able to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to run this code on Windows is somewhat nonsensical.  As a very basic level, `/bin/sh` is not available on Windows, so it would fail there.

Secondly, and more directly to the point of your question: `usePTY` uses a `PTY`, or [pseudo-terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal), a concept which does not exist on Windows.  It is very definitely not supported.

Comment: I am kind of new to this so can you tell me what possibel alternative is there to just create a shell which can be accessed through this

Comment: Other than "install linux" I don't know what to tell you.  There's no Bourne shell on Windows, there are no PTYs.